# Is it true that if you read the last three ayat if surah hashr and die on that day you will become a martyr?

Tags: source-identification, martyr

I read that if someone reads the last three ayat of surah hashr in the morning and dies during the day, he will become a martyr. And if someone reads it in the night and dies he will become a martyr. Is this true and can you please tell me ways one can die as a martyr?

Answer (score 1):

There is a (weak) hadith about the virtue of Surah Hashr that the one who recites it shall receive the reward of a martyr.

> من قال حين يصبح ثلاث مرات: أعوذ بالله السميع العليم من الشيطان الرجيم، ثم قرأ الثلاث آيات من آخر سورة الحشر، ... **إن مات في ذلك اليوم مات شهيدا**، ومن قالها حين يمسي كان بتلك المنزلة
>
> whoever says three times when he gets up in the morning: '*A'udhu Billahis-Sami Al-'Alim Min Ash-Shaitanir-Rajim*' and he recites three Ayat from the end of Surah Al-Hashr ... If **he dies on that day, he dies a martyr**, and whoever reaches the evening, he holds the same status."
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/731660)</sup>

Al-Suyuti in [أبواب السعادة في أسباب الشهادة](https://ia800502.us.archive.org/15/items/waq18470/18470.pdf) has collected around 60 causes of death which receive the reward like that of a martyr, please refer to that.